# ¿Cómo obtener la huella digital para usar API Youtube?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando usar la API de Youtube pero resulta que me quedo atascado aquí. No puedo pasar de aquí porque no se como continuar y obtener.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dónde tengo que poner ese comando que me están diciendo para obtener la Huella digital de certificado ?? He probado en el terminal de Android Studio pero me salta error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Rodry, estas definiendo incorrectamente la ruta de tu keystore, asegura que esta sea correcta y que este archivo keystore que indicas exista en realidad.

Comment: Si el keystore ese tenía que haberlo creado yo, no lo he hecho, porque no sabía que tenía que hacerlo, solo viene este problema al necesitarlo para usar la API de Youtube..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi caso, suelo obtenerlo a través del mismo Android Studio.

Te ubicas a la derecha del IDE, en la pestaña Gradle.

[image]

Luego de ejecutar el signingReport, te muestra un reporte con los datos que necesitas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No encuentro esa vista para que me muestre las carpetas y los archivos así.. Vamos que no enuentro donde está eso..

Comment: Esto únicamente sirve para obtener el SHA-1 del keystore de desarrollo , cuando publiques tu aplicación a Google Playstore.

Comment: @Rodrypaladin te dejo un link como guía https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ3eXOLvy4c.

Comment: @Jorgesys no necesariamente también se puede obtener el SHA1 del release.

Comment: Ahora si que si. Gracias por el vídeo @MVPFrans

Answer (score 2):

Para esto necesitas el paquete de tu aplicación y la SHA-1 de tu Keystore, ya sea de desarrollo o de producción si es que esta aplicación será publicada en Google

ubica primeramente el directorio donde se encuentra instalado Java,

En **windows** generalmente se encuentra dentro de:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<VERSION>\
```

dentro se encuentra el directorio `\bin` y es aquí donde se encuentra la utilería `keytool.exe`

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin
```

En **MAC** `keytool` se encuentra en:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<VERSION>.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

aquí puedes hacer uso de `terminal` y realizas el mismo procedimiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde aquí puedes llamar `keytool.exe` y el siguiente paso es obtener el SHA-1 del keystore con el cual firmaras tu aplicación:

> `keytool -list -v -keystore <Ruta donde se encuentra el Keystore>`

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero la verdad es que me suena totalmente a chino absolutamente todo. Uso mac y no encuentro la ubicación de donde se me guarda Java, busqué por internet, pero las direcciones que me salen no me aparecen a mi

Comment: @Rodrypaladin en MAC agregue donde se encuentra Keytool.

Comment: Ese es el tema, No se que es keytool, ni si lo tengo, ni si tengo que hacer algo para tenerlo

Comment: @Rodrypaladin Keytool es una utilería que ayuda a crear un Keystore u obtener sus propiedades, en este caso el SHA-1 si usas Mac entra al directorio que indico en mi respuesta y puedes ejecutarlo.

Comment: Pero donde indicas ? No se donde tengo yo el keytool ese